# Can I use Bisection search method to find the maximum of following kind of function?

Tags: optimization, convex-optimization, bisection

I have a function $f(x)$ defined over $0<x<\bar{x}$. The function is negative for $0\leq x<x_L$ and then it becomes positive for certain range of $x$ $x_L\leq x<x_U$. Further, I know that the function is quasiconcave for $x_L\leq x<\bar{x}$. (Please note that $x_U<\bar{x}$ and in my problem I also do not know what is the exact $x_L$ but I know for sure that there is some $x_L<x_U<\bar{x}$) Can I use bisection search method to find the value of $x$ which maximizes this function? Any help in this regard will be much appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Comment: So your question is if the bisection method works for maximizing a quasiconcave function?

Comment: @LinAlg I know that Bisection method can be used to maximize a quasiconcave function (I read it in Boyd book) but as I mentioned in my problem that my function is quasiconcave only over a certain domain not over all the domain. Further I do not know the starting point of that domain. In this case can we use bisection method? Thats my question

Comment: Well, the maximum obviously doesn't occur for $x\leq x_L$, so you can restricht the search to $[x_L,\bar{x}]$.

Comment: @LinAlg but I do not know what is $x_L$. I only know that there is some $x_L$.

Comment: You can incorporate this into bisection search. If the function value at a point is negative, you have to continue your search to the right of that point.